# Is there a tool for showing mathematical expressions intuitively in Python comments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It's not easy to understand a python project where many complicated mathematical operations are involved. So I want to add comments on some functions with their corresponding mathematical operations to make my mind lucid.

I can write latex-form mathematical expressions in Python comments, but obviously, it's not intuitive.

For example,

```py
def normalize_adj(adj):
    '''
    operation: \frac{1}{\sqrt{d_h} } \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{d_t} }
    '''
    adj = sp.coo_matrix(adj)  
    rowsum = np.array(adj.sum(1))  
    d_inv_sqrt = np.power(rowsum, -0.5).flatten()  
    d_inv_sqrt[np.isinf(d_inv_sqrt)] = 0. 
    d_mat_inv_sqrt = sp.diags(d_inv_sqrt)  
    return d_mat_inv_sqrt.dot(adj).transpose().dot(d_mat_inv_sqrt).T
```

is there a tool to present the view of the mathematical expression as?

[image]

Comment: You cant really display this in a text file, which is read by a normal text editor. Have you considered storing your files as ipyb notebooks. There you have access to almost every tool and they can easily acheive this task.